# React Navigation 5 Tab.Navigator sending token between Tab.Screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-native-tabnavigator

I am struggling to pass token from one Tab.Screen to another Tab.screen

I am using Tab.Navigator inside Stack.Navigator

`<Stack.Screen name="Auth"/>` component navigates to `<Tab.Screen name="Map"/>` and sends token there:

`props.navigation.replace("BottomTabs", {screen: "Map", params: {token: token}});`

To this point everything is fine, but now I have two Tabs `<Tab.Screen name="Map"/>` and `<Tab.Screen name="List"/>`. I need to pass token from Map component to List component by pressing navigation Tab. I cannot pass it like before with props.navigation.replace/navigate or anything like this.

Maybe someone could help me find a proper way to pass data between one tab screen to another? Thanks!

Comment: Store your token in a global store instead of sending in params. It's like a global state, not a parameter for a screen (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#what-should-be-in-params). You likely need the token almost everywhere anyway, passing it in params is very inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found what seems the best solution in my case:
https://dev.to/efearas/how-to-usecontext-and-set-value-of-context-in-child-components-in-3-steps-3j9h

I create context file `auth-context.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
```

I create token hook in `App.js` and wrap it on like this:

```
import { AuthContext } from "./auth-context.js";

function AppNavigator() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[token, setToken]}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Auth">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="BottomTabs"
            component={BottomTabs} // this separate navigator has my map and list components and they also get token in this way
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Auth"
            component={Auth}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            // other components which I don't want to have in BottomTabs
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
```

In my `auth.js` component, I `setToken`:

```
import { AuthContext } from "../auth-context.js";

export default function Auth(props) {

    const [token, setToken] = useContext(AuthContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
            if (token)
                setToken(token);
                props.navigation.replace("BottomTabs", {screen: "Map"});
        })()
    }, []);
```

here, for example, it tries to get token from AsyncStorage and if it does, it set it to Context Hook (if I can call it this way) and then navigates to Map screen (which is on child Tab.Navigator). Anyway, this is just my project complexity with React Navigation 5. :)

When the token is set, you can access it in other components in the same manner:

```
import { AuthContext } from "../auth-context.js";

....

const [token, setToken] = useContext(AuthContext);
```

Disclaimer: I am far from an expert, so my solution may not be the prettiest, but it works for me and I hope the answer to my struggles will help someone else too :).

If anyone sees what could be done better, please add your answer. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

U can store the data in Context and get It. or u can pass the data by navigate("Route",{param}) and get it in other class by route.param. Or u can send data as a props.